# How to create my own Encoder and Decoder in PHP

Tags: php, decode, encode

I have created a form in which i want to encode the unique id then send to other page. Means I want to create my own Encoder and Decoder using PHP

Answer (score 0):

you can encode using uuencode function try to use this example

```
<?php

//encode string

$str="www.facebook.com";
$encode=convert_uuencode($str);
echo $encode;

$decode=  convert_uudecode($encode);
echo $decode;

?>
```